# Is it safe to `Send` struct containing `Rc` if strong_count is 1 and weak_count is 0?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I have a struct that is not `Send` because it contains `Rc`. Lets say that `Arc` has too big overhead, so I want to keep using `Rc`. I would still like to occasionally `Send` this struct between threads, but only when I can verify that the `Rc` has strong_count 1 and weak_count 0.

Here is (hopefully safe) abstraction that I have in mind:

```rust
mod my_struct {
    use std::rc::Rc;

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct MyStruct {
        reference_counted: Rc<String>,
        // more fields...
    }

    impl MyStruct {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            MyStruct {
                reference_counted: Rc::new("test".to_string())
            }
        }

        pub fn pack_for_sending(self) -> Result<Sendable, Self> {
            if Rc::strong_count(&self.reference_counted) == 1 &&
               Rc::weak_count(&self.reference_counted) == 0
            {
                Ok(Sendable(self))
            } else {
                Err(self)
            }
        }

        // There are more methods, some may clone the `Rc`!
    }

    /// `Send`able wrapper for `MyStruct` that does not allow you to access it,
    /// only unpack it.
    pub struct Sendable(MyStruct);

    // Safety: `MyStruct` is not `Send` because of `Rc`. `Sendable` can be
    //         only created when the `Rc` has strong count 1 and weak count 0.
    unsafe impl Send for Sendable {}

    impl Sendable {
        /// Retrieve the inner `MyStruct`, making it not-sendable again.
        pub fn unpack(self) -> MyStruct {
            self.0
        }
    }
}

use crate::my_struct::MyStruct;

fn main() {
    let handle = std::thread::spawn(|| {
        let my_struct = MyStruct::new();
        dbg!(&my_struct);

        // Do something with `my_struct`, but at the end the inner `Rc` should
        // not be shared with anybody.

        my_struct.pack_for_sending().expect("Some Rc was still shared!")
    });

    let my_struct = handle.join().unwrap().unpack();
    dbg!(&my_struct);
}
```

I did a demo on the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a117786de90cc8e99297dbc3d71bc2c).

It works. My question is, is it actually safe?

I know that the `Rc` is owned only by a single onwer and nobody can change that under my hands, because it can't be accessed by other threads and we wrap it into `Sendable` which does not allow access to the contained value.

But in some crazy world `Rc` could for example internally use thread local storage and this would not be safe... So is there some guarantee that I can do this?

I know that I must be extremely careful to not introduce some additional reason for the `MyStruct` to not be `Send`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.**

There are multiple points that need to be verified to be able to send `Rc` across threads:

1. There can be no other handle (`Rc` or `Weak`) sharing ownership.
2. The content of `Rc` must be `Send`.
3. The implementation of `Rc` must use a thread-safe strategy.

Let's review them in order!

**Guaranteeing the absence of aliasing**

While your algorithm -- checking the counts yourself -- works for now, it would be better to simply ask `Rc` whether it is aliased or not.

```
fn is_aliased<T>(t: &mut Rc<T>) -> bool { Rc::get_mut(t).is_some() }
```

The implementation of [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.get_mut) will be adjusted should the implementation of `Rc` change in ways you have not foreseen.

**Sendable content**

While your implementation of `MyStruct` currently puts `String` (which is `Send`) into `Rc`, it could tomorrow change to `Rc<str>`, and then all bets are off.

Therefore, the sendable check needs to be implemented at the `Rc` level itself, otherwise you need to audit any change to whatever `Rc` holds.

```
fn sendable<T: Send>(mut t: Rc<T>) -> Result<Rc<T>, ...> {
    if !is_aliased(&mut t) {
        Ok(t)
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Thread-safe `Rc` internals**

And that... cannot be guaranteed.

Since `Rc` is not `Send`, its implementation can be optimized in a variety of ways:

- The entire memory could be allocated using a thread-local arena.
- The counters could be allocated using a thread-local arena, separately, so as to seamlessly convert to/from `Box`.
- ...

This is not the case at the moment, AFAIK, however the API allows it, so the next release could definitely take advantage of this.

---

What should you do?

You could make `pack_for_sending` `unsafe`, and dutifully document all assumptions that are counted on -- I suggest using `get_mut` to remove one of them. Then, on each new release of Rust, you'd have to double-check each assumption to ensure that your usage if still safe.

Or, if you do not mind making an allocation, you could write a conversion to `Arc<T>` yourself (see [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed7d485b14c036c327a21a564653b34c)):

```
fn into_arc<T>(this: Rc<T>) -> Result<Arc<T>, Rc<T>> {
    Rc::try_unwrap(this).map(|t| Arc::new(t))
}
```

Or, you could write a RFC proposing a `Rc <-> Arc` conversion!

The API would be:

```
fn Rc<T: Send>::into_arc(this: Self) -> Result<Arc<T>, Rc<T>>

fn Arc<T>::into_rc(this: Self) -> Result<Rc<T>, Arc<T>>
```

This could be made very efficiently inside `std`, and could be of use to others.

Then, you'd convert from `MyStruct` to `MySendableStruct`, just moving the fields and converting `Rc` to `Arc` as you go, send to another thread, then convert back to `MyStruct`.

And you would not need any `unsafe`...

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `Arc` and `Rc` is that `Arc` uses atomic counters. The counters are only accessed when the pointer is cloned or dropped, so the difference between the two is negligible in applications which just share pointers between long-lived threads.

If you have never cloned the `Rc`, it is safe to send between threads. However, if you can *guarantee* that the pointer is unique then you can make the same guarantee about a raw value, without using a smart pointer at all!

This all seems quite fragile, for little benefit; future changes to the code might not meet your assumptions, and you will end up with Undefined Behaviour. I suggest that you at least try making some benchmarks with `Arc`. Only consider approaches like this when you measure a performance problem.

---

You might also consider using the [`archery` crate](https://crates.io/crates/archery), which provides a reference-counted pointer that abstracts over atomicity.

Comment: While I agree that using `Arc` may be the easiest solution possibly with no or small performance hit, this does not answer my question. My question is: "Is the code I posted safe? If not, why?" You are not correct about not being able to clone the `Rc` at all - you may clone it, then drop the clones, then you can verify that they are gone using `strong_count` and `weak_count`.

Comment: Actually if you can give me source for the statement "If you have never cloned the Rc, it is safe to send between threads.", then that would most likely answer my question.

Comment: @michalsrb (apart from [this source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/liballoc/rc.rs)), it's just logic: there is no risk of data races on a variable that doesn't change, and which is only accessible in one thread!

Comment: That is true in today's implementation. But it could change tomorrow. Some types, e.g. `Box` or `Vec` provide guarantees that the internals will remain the same, I am not sure about `Rc`. But I guess it is mostly safe to assume it won't change to something crazy (e.g. using thread local storage).

Comment: @michalsrb The principle of an `Rc` is not complex. It's difficult to imagine the fundamentals of the implementation changing.