# How to pass a struct with Rc fields between threads (without simultaneous access)

Tags: rust

I have the following (simplified) code that spawns a few threads that do long and complex operations to build a `Transactions` struct. This `Transactions` struct contains fields with `Rc`. At the end of the threads I want to return the computed `Transactions` struct to the calling thread through an `mpsc::channel`.

```
use std::thread;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Transaction {
  id: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Transactions {
  list: Vec<Rc<Transaction>>,
  index: HashMap<String, Rc<Transaction>>,
}

fn main() {
  
  let (tx, rx) = channel();
  
  for _ in 0..4 {
    tx = Sender::clone(&tx);
    thread::spawn(move || {
      // complex and long computation to build a Transactions struct
      let transactions = Transactions { list: Vec::new(), index: HashMap::new() };
      tx.send(transactions).unwrap();
    });
  }
  
  drop(tx);

  for transactions in rx {
    println!("Got: {:?}", transactions);
  }

}
```

The compiler complains that `std::rc::Rc<Transaction>` cannot be sent safely between threads because it does not implement the `std::marker::Send` trait.

```
error[E0277]: `std::rc::Rc<Transaction>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:23:5
    |
23  |     thread::spawn(move || {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::rc::Rc<Transaction>` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<Transaction>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<std::rc::Rc<Transaction>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<std::rc::Rc<Transaction>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `std::vec::Vec<std::rc::Rc<Transaction>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Transactions`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Transactions>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:23:19: 27:6 tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<Transactions>]`
```

I understand the I could replace `Rc` by `Arc`, but was looking to know if there was any other solution to avoid the performance penalty of using `Arc`, because the `Rc` structs are never accessed by two threads at the same time.

Comment: `Rc` is for within threads, `Arc` is for between threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to \`Send\` struct containing \`Rc\` if strong\_count is 1 and weak\_count is 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977260/is-it-safe-to-send-struct-containing-rc-if-strong-count-is-1-and-weak-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't delete this post as this is the accepted answer but I want to point to this link that I missed before:

[Is it safe to `Send` struct containing `Rc` if strong_count is 1 and weak_count is 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977260/is-it-safe-to-send-struct-containing-rc-if-strong-count-is-1-and-weak-count)

> Since Rc is not Send, its implementation can be optimized in a variety of ways. The entire memory could be allocated using a thread-local arena. The counters could be allocated using a thread-local arena, separately, so as to seamlessly convert to/from Box…. This is not the case at the moment, AFAIK, however the API allows it, so the next release could definitely take advantage of this.

---

**Old Answer**

As you don't want to use `Arc`, you could use the new type pattern and wrap `Rc` inside a type that implements `Send` and `Sync`. These traits are `unsafe` to implement and after doing so it's all upto you to ensure that you don't cause undefined behaviour.

---

Wrapper around `Rc` would look like:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct RcWrapper<T> {
    rc: Rc<T>
}

impl<T> Deref for RcWrapper<T> {
    type Target = Rc<T>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.rc
    }
}

unsafe impl<T: Send> Send for RcWrapper<T> {}
unsafe impl<T: Sync> Sync for RcWrapper<T> {}
```

Then,

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Transactions {
    list: Vec<RcWrapper<Transaction>>,
    index: HashMap<String, RcWrapper<Transaction>>,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61cbe58c1b3e6c472a69379ab242b21e)

Although, `Deref` trait is not very much worth in this case as most functions are associated. Generally `Rc` is cloned as `Rc::clone()` but you can still use the equivalent`rc.clone()` (probably the only case where `Deref` might be worth). For a workaround, you could have wrapper methods to call `Rc`'s methods for clarity.

**Update**:

Found [send_wrapper](https://crates.io/crates/send_wrapper) crate which seems to serve that purpose.

You could use it like:

```rust
use send_wrapper::SendWrapper;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Transactions {
    list: Vec<SendWrapper<Rc<Transaction>>>,
    index: HashMap<String, SendWrapper<Rc<Transaction>>>,
}
```

PS: I would suggest to stick with `Arc`. The overhead is generally not that high unless you make alot of clones frequently. I am not sure how `Rc` is implemented. `Send` allows type to be sent into other threads and if there is anything thread-local, such as thread local locks or data, I am not sure how that would be handled.

Answer (score 1):

### Just DO NOT do it.

I was making this a comment, but I think it actually answers your question and warns others.

This seems very unsound! Rc is not about managing access, it’s about making sure something lives long enough to be shared between different “owners”/“borrowers” by counting how many references are alive. If there are two (Rc) references to the same value in two different threads, the lack of atomicity could cause two threads to change the reference count AT THE SAME TIME, which could lead to the record being smudged, which could cause memory leaks, or worse, prematurely dropping the allocation and UB.

This is because of the classic sync problem of incrementing a shared variable:

#### Steps of incrementing a variable:

1. Read variable and store it in the stack.
2. Add 1 to the copy in the stack.
3. Write back the result in the variable

That’s all fine with one thread, but let’s see what could happen otherwise:

#### Multithreaded sync incident (Threads A & B)

1. x=0
2. A: read x into xa (stack), xa = 0
3. B: read x into xb, xb =0
4. A: increment xa, xa = 1
5. A: write xa to x, x =1
6. B: increment xb, xb = 1
7. B: write xb to x, x = 1
8. x is now 1

You have now incremented 0 twice, with the result being 1: BAD!

If x was the reference count of an Rc, it would think only one reference is alive. If one reference is dropped, it will think there’s no more reference alive and will drop the value, but there’s actually still a reference out there that thinks it’s ok to access the data, therefore Undefined Behaviour, therefore VERY BAD!

The performance cost of Arc is negligible compared to everything else, it’s absolutely worth using.

Comment: Yes, although I would like stressing the point that `Rc` is not `Send` and if it uses something thread local, it would probably be undefined behaviour. Ref counts is also an important point but not sure if it would have any effect unless you make a clone.

Comment: @Mihir Sync problems can also happen on drop, it’s just not worth it.

Comment: I agree that it is not a good idea to send `Rc` as it is not `Send`. Just for understanding, let's assume it was `Send` and nothing was thread local. In that case, how would it be problematic if there were no clones and it was sent to another thread?

Comment: @Mihir If there’s a Rc, it’s because there’s more than one reference, if both dropped at the same time, it could cause memory leakage. The problem is that it does not sync properly.

Comment: OP states **"the Rc structs are never accessed by two threads at the same time"** This answer assumes all threading is concurrent and discusses that instead.