# How to Acces an Rc Value in Different Threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I want to access a struct in different threads which contains some `Rc` data. To keep it simple, let's only consider a pure `Rc` here:

So this is the naive approach which obviously doesn't work because `Rc` does not implement `Send` (there could be some data race when modifying the internal counter).

```rust
let mut a = Rc::new(42);

let threads : Vec<_> = (0..2).map(|i|
    std::thread::spawn(|| *Rc::get_mut(&mut a).unwrap() += i)
).collect();
    
threads.iter().for_each(|t| t.join().unwrap());
```

But when I wrap the `Rc` in a Mutex, no data-race should be possible. Nevertheless, the following still fails:

```rust
let m = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Rc::new(42)));

let threads: Vec<_> = (0..2)
    .map(|i| {
        let m = m.clone();
        std::thread::spawn(|| {
            let mut a = m.lock().unwrap();
            *Rc::get_mut(&mut a).unwrap() += i
        })
    })
    .collect();

threads.iter().for_each(|t| t.join().unwrap());
```

```
error[E0277]: `Rc<i32>` cannot be sent between threads safely
```

So, why doesn't this work and what would be a way to access the `Rc` in multiple threads?

Comment: Rc does not implement Send. Why not use Arc directly, it is a thread safe version of Rc?

Comment: Because the Rc is nested deeply in some other structs which I don't want to touch if there is no need to

Comment: Also, I want to better understand the `send` trait. If the main difference between `Rc` and `Arc` is, that the atomicity makes it thread safe, then the same should be achievable with a mutex, right?

Comment: [Is it safe to `Send` struct containing `Rc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977260/is-it-safe-to-send-struct-containing-rc-if-strong-count-is-1-and-weak-count) should answer those questions

Comment: It does! Then this can be closed as duplicate! Thanks a lot!